# Создание динамической страницы в плагине Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Добрый день. Разрабатываю простенький плагин. Как в коде создать динамическую кастомную страницу, привязанную к данному плагину (например, WooCommerce имеет `/shop`, `/cart` и т. п.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce создает страницы cart и shop при установке. Cart содержит шорткод. А страница shop имеет пустое содержание.

Наполнить ее можно по-разному. Например, следующим образом (код в `function.php`):

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_page' );
function my_plugin_page() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if ($path == '/my_plugin_page/') {
        ?>
        <div>"Это страница моего плагина"</div>
        <?php
        die();      
    }
}
```